# How to fill the empty record per group using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I am trying to handle the sql query in order to get what I want.

Below is the schema of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_LOG (
    RANKING      VARCHAR(20)   
  , DAYOFWEEK      VARCHAR(10) 
  , MENU     VARCHAR(10)   
)
```

I have inserted some values and it looks like as below.

```
Ranking   DAYOFWEEK   MENU
1         MONDAY      PIZZA 
2         MONDAY      ICE CREAM
3         MONDAY      CHICKEN
4         MONDAY      RICE
5         MONDAY      BREAD
1         TUESDAY      PIZZA 
2         TUESDAY      ICE CREAM
3         TUESDAY      CHICKEN
4         TUESDAY      RICE
1         WEDNESDAY      PIZZA 
2         WEDNESDAY      ICE CREAM
3         WEDNESDAY      CHICKEN
```

As you can see, for each day of week, the ranking is shown with its menu.
However, for Tuesday and Wednesday they have only four and three records.
So I would like to insert the blank record as shown below.

```
Ranking   DAYOFWEEK   MENU
1         MONDAY      PIZZA 
2         MONDAY      ICE CREAM
3         MONDAY      CHICKEN
4         MONDAY      RICE
5         MONDAY      BREAD
1         TUESDAY      PIZZA 
2         TUESDAY      ICE CREAM
3         TUESDAY      CHICKEN
4         TUESDAY      RICE
5         -            -
1         WEDNESDAY      PIZZA 
2         WEDNESDAY      ICE CREAM
3         WEDNESDAY      CHICKEN
4         -              -
5         -              -
```

I have tried to resolve this issue but failed.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` with a subquery which does `CORSS JOIN` get a result `RANKING` &    `DAYOFWEEK` Cartesian product

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.RANKING,
       t2.DAYOFWEEK,
       t2.MENU
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT t1.DAYOFWEEK,t2.RANKING
  FROM MY_LOG t1
  CROSS JOIN MY_LOG t2
) t1 LEFT JOIN  MY_LOG t2
ON t1.RANKING = t2.RANKING 
AND t1.DAYOFWEEK = t2.DAYOFWEEK
ORDER BY t1.DAYOFWEEK,t1.RANKING;
```

| RANKING | DAYOFWEEK | MENU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MONDAY | PIZZA |
| 2 | MONDAY | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | MONDAY | CHICKEN |
| 4 | MONDAY | RICE |
| 5 | MONDAY | BREAD |
| 1 | TUESDAY | PIZZA |
| 2 | TUESDAY | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | TUESDAY | CHICKEN |
| 4 | TUESDAY | RICE |
| 5 |  |  |
| 1 | WEDNESDAY | PIZZA |
| 2 | WEDNESDAY | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | WEDNESDAY | CHICKEN |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/srhRmeC7h7Dc5EmVPLsL8a/0)

Comment: Great answer. I found you had mis typo which is `CORSS`

Answer (score 1):

when you want the other days of the week included too:

```
with recursive weekdays as (
   select dayname(curdate()) dn, curdate() as d 
   
   union all 
   
   select dayname(d+1),d+1 
   from weekdays 
   where d+1<date_add(curdate(), interval 7 DAY)
),
oneTofive as (
   select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5)
select 
   COALESCE(MY_LOG.RANKING, oneTofive.n) as Ranking,
   weekdays.dn as Weekday,
   MY_LOG.Menu
   
from weekdays
cross join oneTofive 
left join MY_LOG ON MY_LOG.DAYOFWEEK = weekdays.dn AND oneTofive.n=MY_LOG.RANKING
order by 
   weekdays.d, 
   COALESCE(MY_LOG.RANKING, oneTofive.n);
```

output:

| Ranking | Weekday | Menu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sunday |  |
| 2 | Sunday |  |
| 3 | Sunday |  |
| 4 | Sunday |  |
| 5 | Sunday |  |
| 1 | Monday | PIZZA |
| 2 | Monday | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | Monday | CHICKEN |
| 4 | Monday | RICE |
| 5 | Monday | BREAD |
| 1 | Tuesday | PIZZA |
| 2 | Tuesday | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | Tuesday | CHICKEN |
| 4 | Tuesday | RICE |
| 5 | Tuesday |  |
| 1 | Wednesday | PIZZA |
| 2 | Wednesday | ICE CREAM |
| 3 | Wednesday | CHICKEN |
| 4 | Wednesday |  |
| 5 | Wednesday |  |
| 1 | Thursday |  |
| 2 | Thursday |  |
| .. | etc.. |  |